# why is an md5sum of a micro SD different after I mount it?

Tags: disk-image

On Linux I dd a binary image to a micro SD card and check each the source and target md5sum, they are identical. I then safely remove the card, and remount the card and do an md5sum again. It is different.

Why?

Thank you,
Bertrand

Answer (score 8):

Each time you mount, and/or open a directory, metadata changes. Data like "number of mounts", maybe even access times, etc. are written to the filesystem, which in turn, changes the `md5sum` of the card.

If you do an md5 only on files residing on the card, they should stay the same.

Comment: Correct, and this is one of the reasons people in forensics always use "write blockers" when accessing storage.

Comment: Another approach would be to generate a list of md5sums, and then generate a md5sum for the list of md5sums. It's a useful trick. `find /path -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | LC_COLLATE=C sort | md5sum` The sort is probably unnecessary but it ensures consistent output.